# Получить текст из 2 ячеек таблицы

Tags: javascript, html

Есть таблица, нужно выделить 2 ячейки и получить текст из них.
Пока могу получить только текст из одной ячейки

```
    let ds = document.getElementById("tb1");
    let tds = ds.querySelectorAll('td');
        tds.forEach(function(itemX) 
        {
            itemX.onclick = function()
            {
                x = itemX.innerText;
                itemX.classList.toggle('bluee');
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если речь идет о стандартном выделении текста мышкой, то используйте [getSelection](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Window/getSelection)

```js
const table = document.getElementById("tb1");
table.addEventListener('mouseup', (e) => {
  if (e.button === 0) {
    const selectedText = window.getSelection().toString();
    alert(selectedText);
  }
});
```

Если выделение ячеек идет за счет клика по ним, то:

```js
let buffer = [];
const table = document.getElementById("tb1");
const cells = table.querySelectorAll("td");
cells.forEach((cell) => {
  cell.onclick = () => {
    if (buffer.length === 2) {
      // Если нажато на 2 ячейки, то берем их содержимое и чистим буфер
      const selectedText = buffer.map((cell) => cell.innerText).join(' ');
      buffer = [];
      alert(selectedText);
    } else {
      // Иначе добавляем ячейку в буфер
      buffer.push(cell);
    }
  };
});
```

Comment: Мне нужно именно нажать на ячейки и получить из них текст

Comment: @outex412 нажать как? Одновременно на две ячейки не нажмешь. Поочередно?

Comment: @outex412 обновил ответ.

Comment: А если это будут числа и мне нужно провести с ними арифметические операции, как мне это сделать?